# use grep or awk to split a column into multiple columns with the headers in the original file headers

Tags: python, bash, awk

I have the following output

```
SRR51XXXX
5
6
7
SRR51XXYY
8
9
1
2
```

and so on..

SO each header file begins with SRR51 and then with unique 4 digit numbers.I want to turn this single column output into separate columns
such as

```
SRR513XXXX            SRR513XXXY 
5                        8
6                        9
7                        1
```

[Fig to show the data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OpIXx.png)

Comment: Is the input from 1 file or 3 files?  Please describe how you get from the input to the desired output, eg, how is it that the input headers don't show up in the output headers (and vice versa)? why are there 3 input headers but only 2 output headers?
 what exactly you 'splitting' (per the subject of your post)?  please review [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and then come back and update your questoin with more details

Comment: The input already has data from 200 files organized in the fashion. Each header begins with "SRR51" with the data listed vertically.

Comment: I would like the output in multiple columns with the each header SRR513XXX.. and corresponding data in the list format.

Comment: Do the data for each header is of fix length? Like 3 rows for each header?

Comment: @user12859525 so what I understood, you have a file which has o/p from around 200 odd files and you want to rearrange the data with header as SRR513XXX and 4 digit below it. Is this what you want?

Comment: I have added a figure to showcase how the data is- its quite long so just a part is shown. But I am wondering how to get the SRRXXXX in separate columns rather than just 1 column as it is now

Answer (score 1):

A simple bash approach:

```
csplit -s -z -f columns sample.txt '/^SRR51/' '{*}'
paste columns* > pivot.txt
rm columns*
```

This will use [`csplit`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/csplit.html) to split the file into individual files based on the ^SRR51 pattern, then [`paste`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/paste.html) all the "columns" separated with `TAB`. Finally rm removes the temporary column files.

If you are stuck with a bsd style csplit use:

```
csplit -s -f columns sample.txt '%^SRR51%' '/^SRR51/' "{$( expr $(grep -c '^SRR51') + 1)}"
```

If you want them "aligned" use `column -t`, but that's not POSIX.

Comment: get `csplit: *}: bad repetition count`

Comment: The output is not showing the columns with corresponding data. It has all the header first and then all the numbers in a column

Comment: @IlyaKharlamov use gnu csplit not the bsd

Comment: @user12859525 columns are separated by `TAB`

Answer (score 0):

awk version:

```
BEGIN {
    field = -1
    row = 0
    maxrow = 0;
}

/^SRR/ {
    row = 0
    field++
}

{
    if (!width[field] || width[field] < length($0)) {
        width[field] = length($0);
    }
    a[row++,field] = $0;
    if (row > maxrow) {
        maxrow = row
    }
}

END {
    for (j = 0; j <= field; j++) {
        printf " %-"width[j]"s ", a[0,j]
    }
    printf "\n";

    for (i = 1; i < maxrow; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j <= field; j++) {
            printf(" %"width[j]"s ", a[i,j])
        }
        printf "\n";
    }
}
```

To run, save into a file col.awk, and then run `awk -f col.awk sample.txt`

Note: headers are left aligned, numbers are right aligned.

Online demo - https://ideone.com/H6hUcq

Answer (score -1):

```
awk '/^SRR/{r=1;c++}{a[r++,c]=$1}END{while(r>i++){while(c>j++){printf "%s\t", a[i,j]}printf "\n";j=0}}' /path/to/my/file.txt
```

Comment: if the second column is longer than the first, this will not work a[r] will not have enough fields

Comment: also, you might consider intializing r in a begin block, your initial variant had a nasty bug if the file didn't contain any SRR ...

Comment: https://ideone.com/IqYiK4 - on the last line, 2 should be in the second column.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/25364811)

Comment: @SuitBoyApps why do you say that 'This does not provide an answer to the question' ? It works fine https://ideone.com/qCYN71

Comment: @IlyaKharlamov no it doesn't you added a line in the input to "make it work" there is no newline between 7 and SRR51XXYY in the asker's sample.

Comment: @Sorin Updated https://ideone.com/bPfebE